# Getting a stack back to previous state after using it c++

Tags: c++, stack

The stack may not fit my needs as well as something else, so if a better data structure is needed please educate me.

I'm trying to retrieve Record objects from most recently created to oldest. These Record objects, I decided, should be pushed into a stack to make retrieval easy. Each Person object in my program has a stack (to keep each Person's Records separate easily), and each Person has a bunch of Records. If I want the n most recently made records, I can just `top()` and `pop()` those n Records and they'll already be in order due to the stack.

However, I just realized that I'm altering the stack contents and thus have just lost all those popped Records.

Is there a better way to achieve my goal of getting the Records in order such that the container is preserved? Please let me know. Thank you.

```
void Person::printAllRecords() {

    while (this->log.size() >= 1) 
    {
        std::string recordType = this->log.top()->checkRecordType(); 
        std::cout << recordType << " made on: "; 
        this->log.top()->displayDateCreated(); 
        this->log.pop(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You could replace your `stack` with a `std::list` or `std::vector` and iterate over it without modifying. Alternatively, you could create a copy of the stack at the beginning of your function and modify that, but doing the copying work would be expensive. I would recommend using `std::list` or `std::vector` in place of stack

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::vector` for iterating through the Records without altering the data in them. You can learn about `std::vector` on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

Initialize vector with your own class :

```
std::vector<CustomClass> log;
for(int i=0; i < numberOfItems; i++){
    CustomClass customClass; 
    //Create object of your class and Initialse it with values.
    log.push_back(customClass);
}
```

Now iterate through your vector :

```
void Person::printAllRecords() {

    for( int i = this->log.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        std::string recordType = this->log.at(i).checkRecordType(); 
        std::cout << recordType << " made on: "; 
        this->log.at(i).displayDateCreated();
    }
}
```